# selection not working on WinJS ListView in click mode

Tags: javascript, listview, winjs

Below is my WinJS.UI.ListView definition. However, onselectionchanged is never called when right clicking or doing Ctrl+Click. I have setup my ListView identically to the samples(which work). Am I missing something? Or could something be interfering, just with the click selection?

```
this.m_listView = new WinJS.UI.ListView(this.domNode,
        {
        layout : {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout},
        itemTemplate : this.itemTemplate.bind(this),
        selectionMode: 'multi', 
        tapBehavior: 'invokeOnly',
        swipeBehavior: 'select'
        });

    this.m_listView.oniteminvoked = this.itemInvoked.bind(this);
    this.m_listView.onselectionchanged = this.selectionChanged.bind(this);
```

**EDIT:** I Assign my datasource in a separate function with these lines

```
var itemList = new WinJS.Binding.List(this.m_nodes);
this.m_listView.itemDataSource = itemList.dataSource;
```

This ListView is wrapped in a javascript class. So my template function is a prototype of my EntriesList class. This is that function(I pulled out the real content for simplicity, I still have this issue with the content though):

```
EntriesList.prototype.itemTemplate = function(itemPromise)
     {
     return itemPromise.then
        (
        function (item) 
            {
            var entry = document.createElement("div");
            entry.className = "tile";
            entry.style.height = "120px";
            entry.style.width = "340px";
            return entry;
            }
       );
```

Comment: A couple of questions: Where do you load your data source into the ListView? Also, I don't understand why you're assigning the results of this.itemTemplate.bind(this) to the itemTemplate property of the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was something in our internal API was blocking pointer events. We were able to resolve the problem. The code/configuration in the question works.